# How to Simplify this mathematical expression

Tags: calculus

I have a mathematical expression but only one side of that . I want to get something easier for this:

## ${a}^{x\log_b a} + {b}^{x \log_a b}$

I do lots of way, I get log from this, I change my variable but it doesn't work because I came back to the first place. 
Is it possible to help me? Thanks.
I'm sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

we have 
$$\log_x y=\frac{\log y}{\log x}$$
so
$${a}^{x\log_b a} + {b}^{x \log_a b}=a^{\frac{x\log a}{\log b}}+b^{\frac{x\log b}{\log a}}$$

Comment: It doesn't seem much easier

Comment: @EugenCovaci I think that the purpose of the question is how to change the log to natural log

Comment: Then you should continue to $\exp(\frac{(\log a)^2}{\log b}x)+\exp(\frac{(\log b)^2}{\log a}x)$ to have $a$ and $b$ all in one place.

Comment: It doesn't seem much easier. I need something that is easier for calculate.

Comment: are you sure there is no a typo in the given term?

Answer (score 0):

note that $$a^{x\log_a b}=b^x$$ and$$ b^{x\log_b a}=a^x$$

Comment: This term is not part of the question.

Comment: i think there is a typo in the given term

Comment: Maybe. But suppositions are not a good basis to give an anser.

Comment: It's not my question. It's different because I know that law.

Comment: how did another user coined it: ''typical Graubnerish trolling''